# How to get 2 values in an array from a recordset

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

It's simple with static data

```
 $items = array( "Great Bittern"=>"Botaurus stellaris",
 "Heuglin's Gull"=>"Larus heuglini" );
```

Now i want to do this with dynamic data from a database

```
 $items = array();

 do{
     $items[] = $row_Recordset1['ID'] => $row_Recordset1['ARTIST'];

 } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1));
```

It worked with just one $row_recordset but when I put the => and second recordset it gives me an error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be like below:

```
$items = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource)) {
  $items[$row['ID']] = $row['ARTIST'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

option 1

```
$items[$row_Recordset1['ID']] = $row_Recordset1['ARTIST'];
```

or maybe

```
 $items[] =array($row_Recordset1['ID'] => $row_Recordset1['ARTIST']);
```